# Origin of Srisailam Hills

Tags: history, temple

Srisailam is a Holy place known which is called [kshetra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kshetram), amongst other things, for hosting [Sri Mallikarjuna Jyotirlingam](http://www.srisailamtemple.com/srisailam/about-the-main-temple.html) and [Goddess Bhramaramba Devi](http://www.shaktipeethas.org/ashtadasa/topic50.html), one of the eighteen Mahashakthi peethas.

The origin of Srisailam Hills has significant conflicting accounts - on the one hand, as stated [here](http://www.srisailamtemple.com/srisailam/legends.html), the sthala is on the hill which is of the body of Parvatha, son of Silada Maharishi whilst according to this [account](https://tirumalatirupativaibhavam.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/contest-between-adisesha-and-vayudeva/) on the other hand, the sthala are part of the tail of [SheshaNaga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shesha).

My question is, which of these accounts is accurate? Is there mention of any of the accounts in Scriptures?

Comment: Parvatha Muni asked Parameswara, he should be turned to Hills and they should be sacred. As per his wish, Shiva makes them the place sacred for everyone. It is place for Varaha Swamy (before arrival of Srinivasa) and Srisaila Jyotirlinga. Garuda only brings Venkatadri hill from Vaikunta, the hill among 7 hills on which Venkateswara Temple is located.  All this is mentioned in Sahyadri Khanda of Skanda Purana which is not yet translated to English.

Comment: Srisailam is the northernmost part of the Eastern Ghats in Andhra, are you saying it is forms a part of the seven hills of Venkateswara? Please clarify.

Comment: Sri Sailam and Tirumala are one and same. Sri Sailam is Sanskrit word for Tamil word Tirumalai. Srisailam (Tirumala) hills are always part of both Vishnu and Shiva worship and this is the whole boon of Parvata Muni. He asked every part of hill should be sacred and many famous temples should be part of it. So, Srinivasa (Vishnu) and Shiva chose Srisailam Hills.

Comment: @TheDestroyer So by this logic, Ahobilam is part of Srisailam?

Comment: Yes. Srisailam Hills have many Punya Kshetras.